# Как сделать скриншот фрагмента сайта?

Tags: php

Добрый день.

Подскажите, как сделать скриншот фрагмента сайта, используя php, без сторонних сервисов (чтоб все библиотеки были непосредственно на сайте)?
Спасибо.

Comment: Никак! Совсем!

Comment: @Роман Ракзин, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Используя только php - никак.

Вы можете сделать скриншот вашего сайта, используя javascript библиотеку html2canvas, а затем отправить полученные данные на сервер, где с помощью php сохранить их как png или jpeg файл.  Но это только для вашего сайта, где вы сможете разместить свои скрипты.

Если хотите сделать возможность создания скриншотов для любого сайта, то создавайте расширение для браузера (для Chrome это сделать несложно) с помощью того же html2canvas и делайте скриншоты хоть всех сайтов подряд.

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоватся сервисом mini.s-shot.ru. Попробуйте так:

```
function screen($url, $razr, $razm, $form, $name)
{
    $toapi="http://mini.s-shot.ru/".$razr."/".$razm."/".$form."/?".$url;
    $scim=file_get_contents($toapi);
    file_put_contents("exemple/screen/".$name.".".$form, $scim); 
    // exemple/screen/ - путь к папке в которую сохранять скрин
}
screen("http://site.com", "1024x768", "600", "jpeg");
```

Comment: Он упал, поэтому вот и решил другими средствами. До этого было на нём.